# does it lead to memory leak?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-leaks

I wrote this code:

```
string getWinTitle(HWND hwnd){
const int MAX_LENGTH = 1000;
wchar_t title[MAX_LENGTH];
ZeroMemory(title, MAX_LENGTH);
GetWindowText(hwnd, (LPWSTR)title, MAX_LENGTH);
char* buffer = new char[MAX_LENGTH];
wcstombs(buffer, title, MAX_LENGTH);
string res = buffer;
return res;
}
```

is there a memory leak here?
do I need to free memory allocated by ZeroMemory?
do I need to explicitly free memory allocated for buffer?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

You need to `delete [] buffer;` since it's `new []` allocated.

[`ZeroMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fills a memory block with 0s, it doesn't do any memory allocation.

Also as a side note, since you're dealing with `wchar_t` arrays, why aren't you using `std::wstring`?

**edit to demonstrate**

```
string getWinTitle(HWND hwnd){
    const int MAX_LENGTH = 1000;
    wchar_t title[MAX_LENGTH];
    ZeroMemory(title, MAX_LENGTH);
    GetWindowText(hwnd, (LPWSTR)title, MAX_LENGTH);
    char* buffer = new char[MAX_LENGTH];
    wcstombs(buffer, title, MAX_LENGTH);
    string res = buffer;

    delete [] buffer; // You must do this, otherwise this is a memory leak if buffer is never deleted

    return res; // res's data is copied from buffer, it is not affected by you doing delete [] buffer
}
```

**Avoiding the memory allocation**

Since you are not using an allocation size dependent on runtime values, you can use stack-allocated arrays:

```
string getWinTitle(HWND hwnd){
    const int MAX_LENGTH = 1000;
    wchar_t title[MAX_LENGTH];
    ZeroMemory(title, MAX_LENGTH);
    GetWindowText(hwnd, (LPWSTR)title, MAX_LENGTH);
    //char* buffer = new char[MAX_LENGTH];
    char buffer[MAX_LENGTH]; // this is on the stack
    wcstombs(buffer, title, MAX_LENGTH);
    string res = buffer;
    return res;
} // buffer is automatically cleaned up
```

Comment: +1  @Michaels:  Please accept this answer if it helped you sufficiently.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, just define `buffer` in the stack and avoid having to deal with memory management altogether.

Comment: David, how to define buffer in stack?

Comment: @michaels123 - `wchar_t title[MAX_LENGTH];` creates `title` on the stack. On the stack basically means not using dynamic memory allocation. For you, you could do `char buffer[MAX_LENGTH]`, since you don't have an array size that is dependent on something at runtime.

Comment: Ok. I see... Does wcstombs allocates a memory and returns pointer to it?  I want to make sure that my function will not return a pointer to memory which was then freed….

Comment: @michaels123 - no, [`wcstombs`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/wcstombs.3.html) does not allocate any memory that you have to delete yourself either. Always check your documentation to see if a function specifies that it dynamically allocates memory that you have to manage yourself.

Comment: birryree, Ok… as far as I understand, this function returns a pointer to the memory which you guys advise me to free.
So if I do it, it will return the pointer to non existing memory… right?

Comment: @michaels123 - no, your function returns what I assume is an `std::string`, which manages its own memory. `string res = buffer` creates a string object from `buffer`, which is a pointer-to dynamically allocated memory. You have to `delete [] buffer;` before you return from the function. `string res` will not be affected because it copies the data from `buffer` and is not tied to the dynamically allocated memory. Check my latest edit for what I'm talking about.